# Using R for lack-of-fit test

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, regression, math-software, regression-analysis

I learnt how to use R to perform an F-test for a lack of fit of a regression model, where $H_0$: "there is no lack of fit in the regression model".

$$F_{LOF} = \frac{MSLF}{MSPE} = \frac{SSLF(\text{model}) / df_1}{SSPE/df_2}$$
where $df_1$ is the degrees of freedom for SSLF (lack-of-fit sum of squares) and $df_2$ is the degrees of freedom for SSPE (sum of squares due to pure error).

In R, the F-test (say for a model with 2 predictors) can be calculated with

`anova(lm(y~x1+x2), lm(y~factor(x1)*factor(x2)))`

Example output:

```
Model 1: y ~ x1 + x2
Model 2: y ~ factor(x1) * factor(x2)
  Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)
1     19 18.122                           
2     11 12.456  8    5.6658 0.6254 0.7419
```

F-statistic: 0.6254 with a p-value of 0.7419.

Since the p-value is greater than 0.05, we do not reject $H_0$ that there is no lack of fit. Therefore the model is adequate.

What I want to know is **why use 2 models** and why use the command `factor(x1)*factor(x2)`? Apparently, 12.456 from `Model 2`, is **magically** the SSPE for `Model 1`.

Why?

Comment: Since I'm not sure whether you know how to check your flag responses: Only questions not older than 60 days can be migrated, so I cannot migrate this. You can re-ask it on a different site in such cases.

Comment: Thank you so much! Will proceed to re-ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/45369472:

---

You are testing whether a model with an interaction improves the model fit.

Model 1 corresponds to an additive effect of `x1` and `x2`.

One way to "check" if the complexity of a model is adequate (in your case whether a multiple regression with additive effects make sense for your data) is to compare the proposed model with a more flexible/complex model.

Your model 2 has the role of this more flexible model. First the predictors are made categorical (by using `factor(x1)` and `factor(x2)`) and then an interaction between them is constructed by `factor(x1)*factor(x2)`. The interaction model includes the additive model as a special case (i.e., model 1 is nested in model 2) and has several extra parameters to provide a potentially better fit to the data.

You can see difference in number of parameters between the two models in the output from `anova`. Model 2 has 8 extra parameters to allow for a better fit but because the p-value is non-significant you would conclude that model 2 (with the extra flexibility based on the additional 8 parameters) actually does not provide a significantly better fit to the data. Thus, the additive model provides a decent enough fit to the data when compared to model 2.

Note that the trick above with making categories (factors) of `x1` and `x2` only really works when number of unique values for `x1` and `x2` is low. If `x1` and `x2` are numeric and each individual has their own value then model 2 is not that useful as you end up with the same number of parameters as you hav observations. In those situations more *ad hoc* modifications such are binning the variables are used.